Ubuntu 24.04 via RDP lacks window elements like minimize button
When accessing Ubuntu 24.04 using RDP (via xrdp), it lacks window elements like the minimize/hide button:

Is there a way to have this element available in a RDP session as well?

I'm using xrdp. The /home/$USER/.xsessionrc file fixed it.

To change the appearance of the desktop from the default gnome to Ubuntu, create the hidden file /home/$USER/.xsessionrc with the following content:
export GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME
export XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg

Source: How to login to the Ubuntu (not GNOME) session on a remote server using xRDP?
Hope this helps
